# DirectX11 pass current backbuffer as a resource to pixel shader

Tags: directx, hook

I'm trying to do a direct 3d 11 "present" function hook and to pass the current backbuffer and the current z-buffer (Depth stencil) as textures to my pixel shader.

I use the following code in my hooked "Present" function:

```
ID3D11RenderTargetView* pRT = NULL;
ID3D11DepthStencilView* pDS = NULL;
pContext->OMGetRenderTargets(1, &pRT, &pDS);
if (pRT != NULL)
{
        ID3D11Texture2D* pBackBuffer = NULL;
    pSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(*pBackBuffer), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC bbDesc;
    pBackBuffer->GetDesc(&bbDesc);

        ID3D11ShaderResourceView* g_refRes = NULL;
        D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shaderResourceViewDesc;

    shaderResourceViewDesc.Format = bbDesc.Format;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D_SRV_DIMENSION_UNKNOWN;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = bbDesc.MipLevels;

    hr = d3d11Device->CreateShaderResourceView(pBackBuffer, &g_shaderResourceViewDesc, &g_refRes);


    d3d11DevCon->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &g_refRes);

 }
```

But when I call CreateShaderResourceView() I get E_INVALID_ARG.

Can anybody help me in how to pass the current backbuffer & z-buffer as textures to a pixel shader?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You say you hook the present method, so I guess you have no control about how the back buffer is created. If a texture is not created using SRV binding, it cannot be used as one. You can create your own texture and copy the content of the back buffer to this texture.

Comment: I tried to do that using DeviceContext->CopyResource() but then when I create the resourceview for the texture using CreateShaderResourceView() for the copied texture2D I also get return value of E_INVALID_ARG. Maybe it's because the Source texture(backbuffer) is on the GPU at this stage?

Comment: You can try to create the SRV in a test project with a debug device (using the description above). This will tell you what problem causes the E_INVALID_ARG. The D3D_SRV_DIMENSION_UNKNOWN looks a bit suspicious to me.